# How to add a new bucket value in HashMap?

Tags: java-collections-api

I have written this small code (below) -

Its showing the output `Singh`. I want to know how can I add Patel and Singh both the values with the single key **s** ?

```
import java.util.*;
public class Practice {
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        String s="Sameer";
        HashMap<String,String> map=new HashMap();
        map.put(s, "Patel");
        map.put(s, "Singh");
        String value=map.get(s);
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

Like s -> Patel, Singh. s is pointing to both the values.

Comment: You can't. The point of a Map is that a key maps to one value.

Comment: Look up libraries that provide a _multimap_ or do it yourself with `Map<String, List<String>>`

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Basic idea of map is to have unique key

Answer (score 0):

No, It can't be done because there is a unique key for each value in map.

You are getting confused understanding the concepts. ***I would recommend to understand the working of HashMap first. [Link1](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/03/how-hashmap-works-in-java.html) and  [Link2](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/02/how-hashmap-works-in-java.html)***

**I Think your concern here is** to add **new entry object to the same bucket**, but this **doesn't** mean that you can have two values mapped with same key, **No, Not At All !**

Bucket values in HashMap are stored as the Objects of `Entry` Class, ***which has attributes as single key and single Value*** `(Value can be simple object or Collection Object).`

---

### Below are some important points needs to be known to understand working of HashMap -

1. HashMap has a inner class called Entry which stores key-value pairs.
2. Above Entry object is stored in Entry  called table.
3. An index of table is logically known as bucket and it stores first
   element of linkedlist.
4. Key object’s hashcode() is used to find bucket of that Entry object.
5. If two key object ‘s have same hashcode, they will go in same bucket
   of table array.
6. Key object's equals() method is used to ensure uniqueness of key
   object.
7. Value object's equals() and hashcode() method is not used at
       all.

---

## Possible Solution For Your Problem -

**However,** what you need could be achieved by using a ***Collection Object mapped by the key***, you can then iterate over the collection object to read all values.

Below is the example using List -

```
import java.util.*;
 class Practice {
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        String s="Sameer";
        HashMap<String,List<String>> map=new HashMap();
        List<String> lastNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
        lastNameList.add("Patel");
        lastNameList.add("Singh");
        map.put(s, lastNameList);
        List<String> getList=(ArrayList)map.get(s);

        for(String val : getList) {
            System.out.println(val);
        }
    }
}
```

Now the output will be -

```
Patel
Singh
```

---

You can extend this idea to any level. It's up-to you.

*Hope it would help !*

Comment: What i have learnt till now is Hashmap is used to fast retrieval so if there are two objects with the same hash value than both of the object should be searchable with the single key.

Comment: And one more thing if we cant get the arrangement like this key->value1->value2; and so on...than what is the use of hashmap..? if there are 1000 objects we need to store it will require 1000 keys as well..? It dosent sound a good approach having 1000 keys and remember what key is associated which value.

Comment: Updated the answer, try to understand the point no. 5. I think you are getting confused there, also provided the links in the answer,Hope it will make you understand the concepts.